# How to align several rows of buttons with different text in them?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, calculator

I am trying to recreate Microsoft Windows 10 calculator (check it out for reference). I am unable to align all my buttons since the buttons contain different letters and symbols. I want my all buttons to be exactly the same size and be next to each other with no spaces in between them.

Also, while posting this I noticed that my display is sticking out to the right more. Any idea for a fix?

Link to HTML and CSS combined:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpLOjP

HTML:

```
<body>
  <form id="calculatorForm">
    <input type="text" id="display">
    <div class="row">
      <!--percent-->
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&#37;</button>
      <!--sq root-->
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&radic;</button>
      <!--x^2-->
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">x&sup2;</button>
      <!--1/x-->
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&sup1;&frasl;<sub>x</sub></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">CE</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="reset()">C</button>
      <!-- remove -->
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&#8653;</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&divide;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">7</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">8</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">9</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">4</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">5</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">6</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&minus;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">1</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">2</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">3</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&plus;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&plusmn;</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">0</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&sdot;</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">&equals;</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#display {
  font-size: 90px;
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  background: #eee;
  border: solid grey;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  font-size: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row button {
  width: 25%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: calibri;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `vertical-align`.

```
.row button{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. also, any idea whats wrong with my display being closer to the edge on the right? looks like i've set it to 100% width but it doesnt look right.

Comment: text inputs have 1px of padding and a 1px border by default. Remove those or add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your input to fix that.

Comment: removing padding and border off of display solved the issue but a weird line appeared under 3 top buttons. however, using the box-sizing method the issue got resolved. youre an absolute genius, upvoted and marked as solved!